# How to execute a function by pressing the enter key

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make an event that executes a function when a certain key is pressed. I have added an `eventListener`, which looks for a `keypress === 13`(enter key), but it's not woring & I have no error messages on the console. It also seems to me that my `eventListener` has access to my function addItem, which is in the global scope. I really can't figure why it doesnt work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container w-25">
  <div class='header'>
    <input class='mt-50' type='text' id='myInput' placeholder='Add a to-do'>
    <button id='btn' type='button'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <ul id='list'>
      <li>Clean cauldron</li>
      <li>Beat Drago</li>
      <li>Study for B.U.S.E.</li>
      <li>Win quidditch cup</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let myList = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    let cross = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
    span.className = 'close';
    span.appendChild(cross);
    myList[i].appendChild(span);
}



for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let div = this.parentElement
        div.style.display = 'none';
    })
}

btn.addEventListener('click', addItem);

function addItem() {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let myInput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    let newText = document.createTextNode(myInput)
    li.appendChild(newText);
    if (myInput === ''){
        alert('enter a to-do please')
    }else{
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    }

 let span = document.createElement('span');
    let cross = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
    span.className = 'close';
    span.appendChild(cross);
    li.appendChild(span);
    let close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
    for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++)
    close[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let div = this.parentElement
        div.style.display = 'none';
});

}


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('myInput').value= '';
});


myInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.keycode === 13) {
       addItem();
   }; 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

"[keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)" is written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Working example:

```js
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Enter pressed!");
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

Comment: In the future, typo solutions should be posted as a comment, along with a vote to *close the question*. As typos are not helpful to future readers, the questions are considered "off-topic" (there is a closure reason specifically for typos).

Answer (score 3):

You need change `e.keycode === 13` to `e.keyCode === 13`.

Since `e.keycode` evaluates to `undefined`, `undefined === 13` is always `false`.

Comment: You're correct, it seems we answered at the same time.

Comment: In the future, typo solutions should be posted as a comment, along with a vote to close the question. As typos are not helpful to future readers, the questions are considered "off-topic" (there is a closure reason specifically for typos)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `key` property of the event object:

```
myInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.key === 'Enter') {
       addItem();
   }; 
})
```